# Remove comma inside Comma Delimited File csv in SSIS Using Script task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, csv

I'm trying to load multiple csv files into a sql database using SSIS but I'm having some issue reading the csv file.

**This is how the files are coming:**

```
,,,,
ID, Name, Amount, Important_Dates, Company
101, Mark,"157,500",11/18/19, Amazon, Inc
102,Tom, "388,000",11/14/19, Ebay Corp
103,Tim, "484,000",11/25/19, Wish
104,Richard,"384,750",10/5/19, NBA. INC
```

**Every time I try to open the file with SSIS the data get mixed because of the commas inside the values and this is how it looks:**

[image]

**And trying to read the file in a way that all values stay on its own column like:**

[image]

**Note:**
**I'll be running this 2 or 1 times a day that's why I'm trying to automate it.**

And I already tried the code from this page but didn't work:
https://radacad.com/problem-with-comma-values-in-comma-delimited-file

Probably, a script task with C# code before the data flow, that will take care of the commas across all columns might help but I have no idea how to do that.

Any help or idea I'll really appreciate it.
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a c# program to read the file placing all values where comma separated into something like array elements. Then combine particular fields to get the results you want and insert into a database table.

Comment: You should have a connection manager item for whatever the source of this data is, and the connection manager will allow you to set a text qualifier property. Do that, and SSIS should handle this data properly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you !! Please post this as an answer to approve it, I just set " as text qualifier and that resolved the issue with the columns.

Comment: @JC_BI This is done ;) Honestly... I've only used SSIS like this once, and it was several years back, so I wasn't 100% confident in the info, hence just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a connection manager item for whatever the source of this data is, and the connection manager will allow you to set a text qualifier property. Do that, and SSIS should handle this data properly.

Comment: It seems like Amazon, LLC will blow up still unless it is quote wrapped

Comment: @KeithL Yes, but then you have improper CSV data.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSV is not so clean. I have [edited](https://gist.github.com/aborruso/c50629fc445a6e1e6ce856bf27f55da4/revisions) and it's

```
ID,Name,Amount,Important_Dates,Company
101,Mark,"157,500",11/18/19,"Amazon,Inc"
102,Tom,"388,000",11/14/19,Ebay Corp
103,Tim,"484,000",11/25/19,Wish
104,Richard,"384,750",10/5/19,NBA. INC
```

Then you can change the separator using a classic command line tool as Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and convert it from CSV to TSV, running

```
mlr --c2t cat input.csv >output.tsv
```

to have

```
ID      Name    Amount  Important_Dates Company
101     Mark    157,500 11/18/19        Amazon,Inc
102     Tom     388,000 11/14/19        Ebay Corp
103     Tim     484,000 11/25/19        Wish
104     Richard 384,750 10/5/19 NBA. INC
```

And then you should change import separator, choosing tab

Comment: This will work, but setting the text qualifier for the "Amount" (and any other required field) item seems way easier